# Specify different log file locations with Hallengren scripts

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I appreciate Ola Hallengren scripts.  Being new to SQL Server, they've made my life so much easier.  Thank you Mr. Hallengren.

I have 5 user databases that I need to back up at separate times, so instead of using `USER_DATABASES`, I'm providing the database name.  When I created the stored procedures with the script, I specified the Output File Directory as something like `G:\Logs\Backups`. The log files are there, but it would be great to either have the database name in the logfile name, or pass the logfile path as a parameter.

I'm also logging to `dbo.CommandLog`. It would be nice to identify the log file that I'm looking for without looking inside.

Is there a way to do this, without changing `maintenance_solution.sql`?

I don't like the idea of modifying because when an update comes out, those would be gone.  To me, the scripts are quite complicated, as I'm coming up-to-speed with MS SQL and T-SQL.

Any insights are appreciated.

Sherrie

Comment: P.S.  I found where I can change this after-the-fact on the job step 'advanced' tab, so I'll do it there for now.  Not sure if this the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have separate jobs to backup each database, your best bet is to edit that manually.

[image: NUTS]

Unfortunately, the way these [tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps) are implemented, you can only get the database name when it's raised in an alert.

All of the tokens that start with "A-" can't be called the way general information tokens can.

```
Token   Description
(A-DBN) Database name. If the job is run by an alert, the database name value automatically replaces this token in the job step.
(A-SVR) Server name. If the job is run by an alert, the server name value automatically replaces this token in the job step.
(A-ERR) Error number. If the job is run by an alert, the error number value automatically replaces this token in the job step.
(A-SEV) Error severity. If the job is run by an alert, the error severity value automatically replaces this token in the job step.
(A-MSG) Message text. If the job is run by an alert, the message text value automatically replaces this token in the job step.
```

If they could, I'm sure they'd end up in Ola's code here:

```
  BEGIN
    SET @TokenServer = '$' + '(SRVR)'
    SET @TokenJobID = '$' + '(JOBID)'
    SET @TokenStepID = '$' + '(STEPID)'
    SET @TokenDate = '$' + '(STRTDT)'
    SET @TokenTime = '$' + '(STRTTM)'
  END
```

If you try to tack `A-DBN` on to the string, the job will fail.

```
$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SQLLOGDIR))\DatabaseBackup_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTDT))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STRTTM))_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(A-DBN)).txt
```

> Message
>   Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: Variable A-DBN not found).  The step failed.

Hope this helps!